# 400 Bad Request 'Allowed JavaScript Origins' in Magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1, amazon-web-services, amazon

i install amazon v3.0.10 on magento 1.x.

When click checkout by amazon, it show this error

[image]

I tryed add application in amazon account but it not working.

Please help me, thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error even though I have added a link page to my amazon account but it doesn't work. So does anyone have any other solution that can solve this problem? thanks